# Hide element when another div is visible in window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to toggle the class `.hidden` to my sticky menu when either the `#pre-footer` or `#footer` div is visible in the window.

I've been messing with jquery and `scrollTop();` but can't seem to get it going. Any help would be appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
  var tabwrap = $('.tab-wrap');
  var prefooter = $('#pre-footer');
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    tabwrap.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > 300); /* Help! */
    /* .tabwrap should toggle class .hidden when #pre-footer and or #footer is visible in window */
  });
});
```

Fiddle so far: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/4tcjnoxp/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want to toggle the class when the bottom of the viewport is aligned with the bottom of `#pre-footer`. So when the `scrollTop` value + height of the viewport is greater than the position of the top of `pre-footer` + height of `#pre-footer`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var tabwrap = $('.tab-wrap');
  var prefooter = $('#pre-footer');
  var prefooter_top = prefooter.offset().top;
  var prefooter_height = prefooter.height();
  var prefooter_bottom = prefooter_top + prefooter_height;
  console.log(prefooter_bottom);
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    tabwrap.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop_bottom > prefooter_bottom); 
  });
});
```

Comment: And you are nearly there. You should use addClass() in the if statement andf then use removeClass() in your else statement.

Comment: @mdurchholz I just checked again... I think I'm way off! This code does the exact same as the intitial code.

Comment: Cheers gents! But is there a way to query if the `#pre-footer` or `#footer` is being shown in the viewport? As opposed to just saying 300px from the top?

Comment: tabwrap.toggleClass('hidden'); will show hide tab again and again on scroll

Comment: @GavinFriel There certainly is! Get the jQuery offset or position value of #pre-footer on top. Add it to the height of the element and use the result to compare to scrollTop. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You're a wizard @DerekNolan. Cheers mate!

Comment: @GavinFriel No problem chief!

Answer (score 0):

```
var tabwrap   = $('.tab-wrap');
var prefooter = $('#pre-footer');

/**
 * @desc Check to see if element is inside the viewport
 */
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var element     = $(this),
        elementHt   = element.outerHeight(),
        elementTop  = element.offset().top,
        elementBot  = elementTop + elementHt,

        viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        viewportBot = viewportTop + $(window).outerHeight(),

        offset      = 0.35 * elementHt; // pecentage of top and bottom

    return (elementBot - offset) > viewportTop && (elementTop + offset) < viewportBot;
};


function checkOffset()
{
    if( prefooter.isInViewport() )
        tabwrap.addClass('hidden');
    else
        tabwrap.removeClass('hidden');
}

$(window)
.load(function(){ checkOffset(); })
.scroll(function(){ checkOffset(); });
```